# Outer automorphism group of a quasisimple group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian simple group, and let $\tilde{G}$ be a cover of $G$. What can we say about ${\rm Out}(\tilde{G})$ in relation to ${\rm Out}(G)$?

It is easy to show the natural map ${\rm Aut}(\tilde{G}) \to {\rm Aut}(G)$ induces an injection ${\rm Out}(\tilde{G}) \to {\rm Out}(G)$, as follows. First, the map ${\rm Aut}(\tilde{G}) \to {\rm Aut}(G)$ is injective: any element $\phi$ in the kernel induces a map $\tilde{G} \to Z(\tilde{G})$ (defined by $g \mapsto \phi(g) g^{-1}$) which must be trivial since $\tilde{G}$ is perfect.  Thus any automorphism of $G$ lifts to at most one automorphism of $\tilde{G}$. Since any inner automorphism of $G$ lifts to an inner automorphism of $\tilde{G}$, it follows that the induced map ${\rm Out}(\tilde{G}) \to {\rm Out}(G)$ is an injection.

Are there any other general results one can say about ${\rm Out}(\tilde{G})$ in terms of ${\rm Out}(G)$? (Without invoking the classification theorem to enumerate all possibilities.)  For example, can one use the value of $[\tilde{G}:G]$ to narrow down the possibilities even further?

Comment: Every automorphism of $G$ lifts to one of $\tilde G$, so they are isomorphic. This has nothing to do with finiteness. I think the same is true for allperfect groups with trivial centre.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you, that was helpful.

Comment: @DerekHolt just to make sure I'm understanding this correctly, are you saying that for any perfect group $ G $ with trivial center and any perfect central extension $ \tilde{G} $ of $ G $ it is the case that $ Aut(G) \cong Aut(\tilde{G}) $?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira No that's not what I said, and it is not true. It is true for the full covering group of $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt ah ok, and is the more general statement obviously wrong? I mean is there a perfect central extension $ \tilde{G} $ (less than the full Schur covering group) of a perfect group with trivial center $ G $ such that $ Aut(G) $ and $ Aut(\tilde{G}) $ are not isomorphic? I can also just ask this as a new question if you would prefer.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira  An example is $2.{\rm Sz}(8)$ with trivial outer automorphism group. The full covering group is $2^2.{\rm Sz}(8)$ with outer automorphism group of order $3$ (the same as ${\rm Sz}(8)$ itself).